# Use a php variable into javascript

Tags: javascript, php

```
class Map
{
public $Id;
public $longitudes;
public $latitudes;
public $lat_init;
public $lng_init;
public static function createMap($Id){
    global $latitude, $longitude;
    $dbh = Database::connect();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `cartes` WHERE Id=? ";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Map');
    $sth->execute(array($Id));
    if ($sth->rowCount() === 0) return NULL;
    $map=$sth->fetch();
    $sth->closeCursor();
    $lat=$map->latitudes;
    $lng=$map->longitudes;
    $latitude=unserialize($lat);
    var_dump($latitude);
    $longitude=unserialize($lng);
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">'
    ,'var lat =  json_encode($latitude); 
      var lng =  json_encode($longitude);   
      draw(lat,lng);
        '

    ,'</script>';

}  
}
<?php 
$dbh=Database::connect();
Map::createMap(6);
?>
```

When i excute this code, the following error appears: "$latitude is not defined". var_dump($latitude) is ok. I think the script doesn't recognize $latitude but i don't know why. Any help?
thanks

Comment: Hello!  Don't forget to accept an answer, you even get 2 rep for it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're encoding it into JSON, you'll need to wrap it in quotes correctly (you can't call functions inside strings):

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        var lat = '. json_encode($latitude). '; 
        var lng = '. json_encode($longitude). ';   
        draw(lat,lng);
      </script>';
```

Comment: JSON is (a subset of) Javascript literal syntax, so you don't need to use `JSON.parse` -- just substitute the result directly into the JS.

Comment: It _returns_ the string, but when you echo it into the web page, the quotes are not there.

Comment: You could also use $.parseJSON() as a jQuery alternative for better support.

Comment: @KyleNeedham I don't post jQuery answers to questions that don't have a jQuery tag.

Answer (score 4):

With PHP, single quote are for string literals and will use the name of the variable instead of its value.  If you want interpolation (inserting a variable's value into the string), you need to use double quotes.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
    "var lat = ". json_encode($latitude)  .";
     var lng = ". json_encode($longitude) .";   
     draw(lat,lng);",
'</script>';
```

Update: I somehow overlooked the part about `json_encode` being a PHP call... so the interpolation issue is a moot point, since you just need to concatenate the function's output into the string.

Comment: You need to make sure to concatenate the output from PHP function `json_encode` to the JavaScript string.

Answer (score 1):

Functions aren't called inside quoted strings. You need to concatenate it:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
      var lat =  ' . json_encode($latitude) . ';
      var lng =  ' . json_encode($longitude) . '; 
      draw(lat,lng);
     ';
```